# Проблема с денвером

Tags: localhost

Когда устанавливал Denwer, возникла проблема: 80 порт был занят System. Я прочитал, что нужно сменить значение в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Start на 4. Когда я это сделал, денвер заработал. Но компьютер не видит принтеры и служба печати не запускается. Можно как-нибудь устроить всё так, чтобы не изменять каждый раз реестр и не перезагружать компьютер?

Answer (score 2):

в виндовсе 80-й порт любит занимать скайп. поищите в нем настройку и запретите использование 80-го порта.

вешать веб-сервер на порт, отличающийся от 80-го - мучать и себя и всех осталных необходимостью принудительно указывать выбранный нестандартный порт...

Answer (score 0):

Если дело в создании какого-либо интернет проекта, то действительно, лучше поставьте LAMP (Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP) + nginx на виртульную машину, например Oracal VM VirtualBox. И сохраните свою основную систему, которая, как я понимаю, Win, и получите полноценный интернет-сервер для разработки и соответствующие знания.

Answer (score 0):

Выполняете

```
netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:80
```

Получаете вывод типа

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

последнее значение - ID процесса. Смотрите имя процесса в Task Manager.

#### Если там System

Это встроенный в Windows вебсервер IIS. Судя по тому, что ломание реестра вам помогло освободить порт - это ваш случай. Но порт надо было освободить корректно, не отламывая вообще весь http в системе, вместе с принтером, шарингом и прочим. Варианты на выбор:

- или останавливаете службу World Wide Web Publishing Service в Control Panel / Local Services (если вам вообще IIS не нужен).
- или открываете Control Panel / IIS Manager и меняете порт у Default Web Site с 80 на другой.
- или открываете Add/Remove Windows Features и сносите оттуда World Wide Web Publishing целиком.

В русской локализации службу можно остановить открыв Панель управления /  Администрирование / Службы, выбрать Служба веб-публикаций / Остановить.

Чтобы не пришлось делать это после каждой перезагрузки - можно поменять тип запуска службы с автоматического на ручной.

#### Если там скайп

Не ваш случай, но вполне возможен у других с той же проблемой. Идете в настройки скайпа, раздел Advanded / Connections и снимаете там чекбокс с опции "использовать 80 и 443 порты". Перезапускаете скайп.

Если там что-то еще (очень маловероятно, если только вы сами что-то не поставили) - разбираетесь с этим "чем-то еще", настраивая его, и освобождая 80 порт.

Comment: > Выполняете netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:80 Получаете вывод типа
> > TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4
> последнее значение - ID процесса. Смотрите имя процесса в Task
> Manager. Действительно:
> TCP 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4 Процесс 4 у меня - это System (определил с помощью программы Process Explorer). Удалось отключить службу World Wide Web Publishing Service.
На всякий случай, привожу способ отключения в моей русифицированной ОС Windows 8: **Панель управления - Администрирование - Службы (запустить от имени администратора) - Служба веб-публикаций - Остановить** Процесс на порту 80

Answer (score -1):

Простое решение: Использовать порт отличный от 80го (например: 8080).

Более правильное: Выяснить -- кто и зачем использует 80ый порт на вашем компьютере, и, возможно, удалить мешающую программу. Если программа нужна -- см выше.

Если вы собираетесь заниматься профессиональной веб разработкой -- настоятельно рекомендую линукс на виртуалке.

Comment: И не бойтесь нестандартных портов -- вы ж не сервер поднимаете...